# What is the type of the errno variable in C++?

Tags: c++, errno

I was doing some system programming in C++, and I want to pass the errno variable in linux systems to my exception handler. You can see example code in here 
https://pastebin.com/ppgMc8Hj

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <cerrno>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

std::string errorString(int errno){
    return std::strerror(errno);
}

int main(){
    struct stat sb;
    errno = 0;
    if(stat("/jdfj/", &sb)){
        errorString(errno);
    }
    else{
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

But it returns an error like this

```
In function 'int main()': 
 14:26: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int* (*)()' [-fpermissive] 
  6:13: note: initializing argument 1 of 'std::string errorString(int* (*)())'.
```

I have seen here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strerror that the standard function that returns a string from errno accepts an int as argument.
My question is

1. If it is an int type why doesn't it work in the above code?
2. If not what is it's type?

Comment: Even the most casual search reveals that "errno is a preprocessor macro used for ..."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`errno`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errno) is an implementation defined macro that expands to an expression of type `int`.

The problem is you are using the name `errno` as your function argument, which is not allowed. Since the name `errno` is a macro, it's expanded. For me, it results in `std::string errorString(int (*_errno()))`. Your snippet works fine if you change the argument name.

```
std::string errorString(int error_num){
    return std::strerror(error_num);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to François' answer, let's see what the preprocessor output is on a Linux system with GCC. `g++ -E test.cpp` gives:

```
# 6 "test.cpp"
std::string errorString(int 
# 6 "test.cpp" 3 4
                           (*__errno_location ())
# 6 "test.cpp"
                                ){
    return std::strerror(
# 7 "test.cpp" 3 4
                        (*__errno_location ())
# 7 "test.cpp"
                             );
}
```

So `errno` is defined as `(*__errno_location ())` here. It's actually a function call, but if you put `int` in front, it happens to be a legal parameter declaration as well.

Yay for macros.

Comment: Looking forward to this, and htons and all the other macros getting replaced!